# Debugging a micro-processor

Tags: debugging, embedded, microcontroller, jtag

One of our co-processors is an 8-bit microprocessor. It's main role is to control the hardware that handles flash memory. We suspect that the code it's running is highly inefficient since we measured low speeds when reading/writing to flash memory. The problem is, we have only one J-TAG port that's connected to the main CPU so debugging it is not an option. What we do have, is a register that's available from CPU that contains the micro-processor's program counter. The bad news, is that the micro-processor works at a different frequency than the CPU so monitoring it's program counter outside is also hard. Measuring time inside the micro-processor is also very difficult since it's registers are only 8-bit long. Needless to say, the code is in assembly and very complex. How would you go about approaching this problem?

Comment: not exactly sure what you're asking here. what's the problem? you want to be able to debug the microprocessor?

Comment: If you just want to see what the micro is doing, hook up a logic analyser?

Comment: @JasonD We used an oscilloscope and saw delays. We just can't figure who's responsible - our RAM or the code or maybe even the flash.

Comment: writing flash is very slow, period.  figure out if there is anything above and beyond that.  some flashes can be made to go faster depending on which mix of commands you use (but that same mix might be slower on a comparable part from another vendor).  software speed gets involved in the slowness between blocks on the part, and your 8 bit micro might not be able to go any faster or more efficient than it already is.  The simplest flash optimization is to not write 0xFFs, add a little code to check for all ones for a write cycle and skip that cycle.  the optimization becomes data dependent.

Comment: Not sure why you need a coprocessor for the flash only, but you might also loose a significant amount of time for the communication between your main cpu and that 8-bit coprocessor.

Comment: JTAG devices can be daisy chained such that one port lets you talk to several processors.  You should be able to connect to your micro via JTAG.  If that is not the case, then you have a case of extremely major hardware design failure.  Someone should be fired if you built a system where you can't reach the micro via JTAG.

Answer (score 5):

> Needless to say, the code is in assembly and very complex. How would you go about approaching this problem?

I would advise that you start from (or generate) the requirements specification for this part and reimplement the code in C (or even careful use of a C++ subset).  If the "complexity" you perceive is merely down the the code rather than the requirements it would be a good idea to design that out - it will only make maintenance in the future more complex, error prone and expensive.

One of the common arguments for using assembler are size and performance, but more frequently a large body of assembler code is far from optimal; in order to retain a level of productivity and maintainability often "boiler-plate" code is used and reused that is not tailored to the specific situation, whereas a compiler will analyse code changes and perform the kind of "micro-optimisation" that system designers really shouldn't have to sweat about.  Make your algorithms and data structures efficient and leave the target instruction set details to the compiler.

Even without the ability to directly debug on the target, the use of a high-level language will allow prototyping and simulation on a PC for example.

Even if you retain the assembler code, if your development tools include an instruction set simulator, that may be a good alternative to hardware debugging; especially if it supports debugger scripts that can be used to simulate the behaviour of hardware devices.

All that said, looking at this as a "black-box" and concluding that the code is inefficient is a bit of a leap.  What kind of flash memory is appearing to be slow for example? How is it interfaced to the microcontroller? And how have you measured this performance?  Flash memory is intrinsically slow - especially writing and page erase; check the performance specification of the Flash before drawing any conclusion on the software performance.